# Get $scope var outside form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Why button inside ion-nav-buttons dosen't return the user input like the button inside the form?

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon icon" ng-click="login(user)">Signup</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<form>
    Email: <input type="text" ng-model="user.teste" placeholder="test@gmail.com"/><br />    
    <button ng-click="login(user)">Signup</button>
</form>

$scope.login = function(form){
  alert(form.teste)
}
```

Demo:
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/idlex

Comment: `ng-model` binds the variable to the current scope, which in this context is attached only to `<form>`. You need to wrap everything in a div and use a controller's scope.

Comment: but my MainCtrl does not get everything? if i remove <form> not work at all.

Comment: I don't know. You're using ion-??? thing I've never seen before, but I would suspect that the scope from the controller is not being made part of the template view.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create a $scope variable to have the email.

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxzJC